# How can I check if Mobx store is empty in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, mobx

It seems that Mobx populates its observable properties with array of undefined objects. How can I check if they are undefined or if they contain value?

I have a property in Mobx store like this:

```
  @observable object: object[] = [];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `length` property of an observable array works just the same way as a regular array, so `object.length === 0` is all you need to check if your `object` array is empty.

```js
const { observable } = mobx;

const object = observable([]);
console.log(`object is ${object.length === 0 ? 'empty' : 'not empty'}`);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mobx@5.0.3/lib/mobx.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a slice of the array first to convert it to a regular array, and then check the length i.e.

```
object.slice().length > 0
```